# Cannot make ggplot with Arial Narrow font, cannot font_import()

Tags: r, fonts, extrafont

I am using R on Windows 11, and I am not the administrator of my laptop, namely I cannot run R as an administrator. I would like to make a ``ggplot`using`theme_ipsum`, but I have some problems to import the Arial Narrow font on R (actually, I have problems also with Palatino). I tried with` extrafont`, without success:

```
library(extrafont)

font_import(font_import(paths = 
              "C:/Users/Public/R/R4_libs_x86_64/prettydoc/resources/fonts/Arial_Narrow.ttf"))
```

yields

```
Scanning ttf files in C:\windows/Fonts, C:\Users\bulgmat\AppData\Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
C:\Windows\Fonts\ALGER.TTFError in system2(enc2native(ttf2pt1), c(args, shQuote(ttfiles[i]), shQuote(tmpfiles[i])),  : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\Public\R\R4_LIB~1\Rttf2pt1\exec\ttf2pt1.exe -a -G fAe "C:\Windows\Fonts\ALGER.TTF" "C:\Users\bulgmat\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpwpsOIZ/fonts/ALGER"'
```

This is the exact path of the file with the Arial Narrow font on this computer. I have no idea what to do, I tried also with `font_import()` . I can use other fonts like serif, not Arial Narrow.